# Scrollspy definir tamanho

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4

Quero mudar o tamanho da janela onde o scrollspy está.
Pois necessitei de muitos intens e ficou desproporcional segue foto.

[image: Demonstração do problema]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode forçar com jQuery para que a div do scrollspy tenha a mesma altura do menu:

```
$(function(){
   $('["data-spy=scroll"]').css("height", $("ul.nav-pills").outerHeight()+"px");
});
```

No exemplo acima, o seletor `ul.nav-pills` seria o menu. Se estiver usando o mesmo seletor, não precisa alterar, mas se estiver usando outro, uma classe ou id, é só alterar no código (seria recomendável usar um `id` no menu ou uma classe única, para não conflitar com outros elementos).

**O que o código faz?** Ao carregar o DOM, o código pega a altura do menu (elemento com o fundo cinza claro) e coloca na div do scrollspy, o que possui o tributo `data-spy="scroll"`.

Veja um exemplo (execute em tela cheia):

```js
$(function(){
   $("[data-spy=scroll]").css("height", $("ul.nav-pills").outerHeight()+"px");
});
```

```css
ul.nav-pills {
position: fixed;
background: #ddd;
}
#section1 {color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
#section2 {color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
#section3 {color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
#section41 {color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
#section42 {color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}

[data-spy="scroll"]{
position: relative;
overflow: auto;
height: auto;
font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3" id="myScrollspy">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>                     
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section5">Section 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section6">Section 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section7">Section 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section8">Section 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section9">Section 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section10">Section 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-sm-9" data-spy="scroll">
      <div id="section1">    
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section2"> 
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
      </div>        
      <div id="section3">         
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section41">         
        <h1>Section 4-1</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
      </div>      
      <div id="section42">         
        <h1>Section 4-2</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```